# What is the complete story of Rahu and Ketu?

Tags: scripture, rahu, planets, ketu

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/6/6/37/

This link of SB says that ketu was not only 1 graha,it was 100 in number.It says that Rahu was born from Simhika and Viprachitti.

https://vedabase.io/en/library/sb/8/9/24/

This link says that rahu was in disguise and lord Vishnu cut his head.Further it says that,The body of rahu was dead.

But as far as I know,there is a story like there was a demon Svarbhanu who came in disguise and then lord vishnu cut his head.Afterwards, his top part (head) was called rahu and the bottom part (body without head) was called ketu.

So,I want to know everything regarding the two entities Rahu and Ketu like for example.. Their complete story or are there 2 entities named Rahu or is there more than one story (the Samudra Manthan incident) of Rahu and Ketu, etc.

Comment: It is unknown that what happens to Rahu before Samudra Manthan. But, after that, Rahu become Jalandhara's minister and Ketu becomes the lord of numerous planets by Lord Shiva's grace.

Comment: But what about ketu being 100 in number? And what is the meaning of ketu being lord of many planets by lord shiva's grace. @Boovanaes

Comment: And rahu born from simhika? But Svarbhanu came to be known as rahu after head was chopped..so is simhika the parent of svarbhanu or there are 2 rahu etc.

Comment: Many Puranas mention "Rahu" is name of Simhika's son before Samudra Manthan too and Svarbhanu is mentiones in few texts. Actually, there are 2 Svarbhanus, one is Danava and another one is Rahu's another name.

Comment: [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626839.html) of Skanda Purana clarifes your doubt of ketu being the lord of many planets due to Lord Shiva's grace. Hmm... I'll say about Ketu being 100 in number, if i find anything about it.

Comment: Thank you @Boovanaes

Comment: I have recently found some infos about Rahu and Ketu (before and after Samudra Manthan). I'll post it on my answer soon.

Answer (score 1):

### For Rahu

Before Samudra Manthan, there was mostly unknown to what happened to Rahu. But, after Samudra Manthan, Rahu was become the lord of bad omens by Lord Brahma, according to Harivamsha.

As i previously mentioned at comment, he also become Jalandhara's minister. It is mentioned in Shiva, Skanda and Padma Puranas.

Rahu also once worshipped Lord Shiva in form of linga and that linga was known as Rahvishvara. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-skanda-purana/d/doc626838.html) of Skanda Purana mentioned that.

At the end of current Dwapara Yuga, Rahu was incarnated as King Kratha. [This chapter](https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/the-mahabharata-mohan/d/doc4030.html) of Adi Parva from Mahabharata mentioned that:-

> The Graha who was brought forth by Sinhika and who persecuted the Sun and the Moon
> **became noted on earth as the monarch Kratha**.

You can find about Kratha in Wisdomlib.

### For Ketu

**(To be updated)**

Comment: But before samudra manthan, rahu and ketu were part of one entity right?

Comment: Yes, you are correct.